# Derivative of a trace norm or a Frobenius norm of a matrix wrt to a vector

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace

I have a Frobenius norm of a multiplication of two matrices

$||U^TL^\frac{1}{2}||_F^2$

the $L$ matrix is a symmetric matrix, so it can be written as

$tr(U^TLU)$

Now I want to get the derivative of this norm wrt a row vector in $U$, which is $U_i.$ as a vector. Note $U$ is $m \times n$, and $L$ is $m\times m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** With block matrix multiplication, we can rewrite
$$
U^TLU = \pmatrix{U_1^T & \cdots & U_m^T}\pmatrix{L_{11} & \cdots & L_{m1}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ L_{m1} & \cdots & L_{mm}} \pmatrix{U_1\\ \vdots \\U_m} = 
\sum_{i,j = 1}^m L_{i,j} U_i^T U_j
$$
So, we have
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(U^TLU) = \operatorname{Tr}\left[\sum_{i,j = 1}^m L_{i,j} U_i^T U_j\right] = 
\sum_{i,j = 1}^m L_{i,j} \operatorname{Tr}(U_i^T U_j) = 
\sum_{i,j = 1}^m L_{i,j} U_j U_i^T
$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! So the derivative of Tr($U^TLU$) w.r.t to a vector in $U$, say, $U_i$, would be $\sum^{m}_{j=1}L_{i,j}U_j$?

Comment: Actually, I want to get this derivative because it's part of an objective function and I want to optimize $U$, in terms of each of its rows. So I wonder whether this can be written as a form with $U_i$ in it? I got $U_i L_i^T$, but it seems the dimensions of this two vector don't match...

Answer (score 0):

The inner/Frobenius product is a convenient infix notation for the trace, i.e. $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
With this notation the function can be written in a form which is easy to differentiate
$$\eqalign{
f &= {\rm tr}(LUU^T) = L:UU^T \cr
df &= L:(dU\,U^T+U\,dU^T) = 2L:dU\,U^T = 2LU:dU \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial U} &= 2LU \cr
}$$
This is the gradient with respect to the full matrix. To isolate the contribution of the $k^{th}$ row multiply by the corresponding base vector $e_k$ to get
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial U_k} &= e_k^T\frac{\partial f}{\partial U}  \,= 2e_k^TLU \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! Actually, I want to get the derivative of $Tr(U^TLU)$ because it's part of an objective function, and I want to optimize it w.r.t. to a row vector of $U$, say $U_i$. So can the result be the form with $U_i$ in it? Like $2LU_i$, so that I can update one row, not the whole matrix